# ASP.NET CORE 1.1 API REST, in the POST request the parameter always comes null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my Method the param always comes null, but any other request type (get, put, delete) is doesn't happen.

This problem just happens in request type POST.

This is my Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Dificuldade value)
    {

        if (value == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("Get", new { id = value.Id }, value);
    }
```

This is my Model

```
 public class Dificuldade
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Pessoa pela qual passa difilcudade ou relatou o problema
    public string NomePessoa { get; set; }

    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    public string Longetude { get; set; }

    //Descricao da difilcudade
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataHoraRegistrado { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataHoraSolucionado { get; set; }

    public bool Solucionado { get; set; }

    public int BairroId { get; set; }
    public Bairro Bairro { get; set; }

    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }

    //Usuario no qual fez o registro
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
 }
```

And this is my request [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl2Kr.png)

Comment: I am not familiar with Postman but I think you may need to select `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @CodingYoshi No, OP is sending JSON so the Content-Type is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your action accepts an individual object. You are sending an array of them.

So you would need to send something like:

```
{ "id":1, "namePessoa": "Something"... }
```

Instead of:

```
[{ "id":1, "namePessoa": "Something"... }]
```

If instead you wanted to receive a set of objects, you need to change your controller action like this:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]List<Dificuldade> value)
```

Comment: This answer is good but perhaps you may want to suggest a solution: Either change the controller action to accept array or change the request to send one item and not an array.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Edited :)